# Solving $|x-1|^{\log_2(4-x)} \le|x-1|^{\log_2 (1+x)}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

Let us solve

$|x-1|^{\log_2(4-x)}\le|x-1|^{\log_2 (1+x)}......(*)$

Let $4-x>0 ~\& ~1+x>0$.......(1)

**Case 1:** $|x-1|\le 1\implies 0\le x\le 2$........(2)

We get $\log_2(4-x) \color{red}{\ge} \log_2(1+x)\implies 4-x \ge 1+x \implies x\le 3/2$....(3)

The overlap of (1,2,3) gives $x\in [0,3/2]$........(4)

**Case 2:**  $|x-1|\ge 1 \implies x\le 0 ~or~ x\ge 2$....(5)

We get $\log_2(4-x) \color{red}{\le} \log_2(1+x)\implies 4-x <1+x \implies x\ge 3/2$....(6)

Taking overlap of (1,5,6), we get $x \in [2,4)$.

So the final solution is : $[0,3/2] \cup [2,4).$

Now the question is  whether this solution is complete and how else this (*) could be solved?

Comment: Looks good. Quibble: `let 4-x>0...` sounds like you are (provisionally?) imposing some restriction rather than merely observing/inferring the restriction.

Comment: Yes, because the argument oh log have to be positive and this can be said apriori.

Comment: You are not understanding my point: what you wrote there suggests Option A (you imposed the restriction) but you actually mean Option B (you deduced the restriction). This is just a small communication/readability issue, and doesn't affect the substance of your proof.

Comment: Another way could be taking $log_a$ both sides, there would arise two cases when $0<a<1$ and $a>1$. I wonder if there would  arise some more solutions!

Comment: Choosing either of the bases wont change the final answer, you may see my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-1|^{\log_2(4-x)}\le|x-1|^{\log_2 (1+x)}......(1)$
Note that $x=0,1,2$ are already  roots.
Taking $\log_a$ both side ( $a\in (0,1)$ or $a\in(1,\infty))$, let us take $a=2$. We get
$$\log_2(4-x) \log_2|x-1|\color{red}{\le} \log_2(1+x)\log_2|x-1|\quad(2)$$
Since, $\log_2(4-x)$ and $\log_2(1+x)$ have to be real we declare
$$(4-x)>0~\&~ (1+x)>0\quad(3)$$

**Case 1:** $|x-1|<1\implies 0<x< 2, \log_2|x-1|\color{red}{<}0\quad(4)$,

From (2) we get
$$\log_2(4-x)  \color{red}{\ge}  \log_2(1+x) \implies 4-x \ge 1+x \implies x \le 3/2\quad(5)$$
Taking intersection of (3,4,5) and inclusion of $x=0,1$; we get the solution as
$x\in [0,3/2]\quad (6)$

**Case 2:** $|x-1|> 1 \implies x<0 ~or~x > 2, \log_2|x-1|\color{red}{>}0 \quad (7)$

This time from (2), we get
$$\log_2(4-x) \color{red}{\le} \log_2(1+x) \implies 4-x \le 1+x \implies x\ge 3/2 \quad (8)$$
Finally, intersection of (3,7,8) and inclusion of $x=2$, gives the solution as $2\le x< 4 \quad (9)$

So the final solution lies in $[0,3/2] \cup [2,4)$.

**Note** that by choosing the base e.g., $1/2$ wont change the final answer.

Comment: $\log_2 |x-1|$ in equation (2) is not defined if $x=1$.

Comment: @Martin R Yes, in fact before taking $\log$, we should off hand infer that $x=1$ is actually  a solution and then take $ log$. Thanks, I sm going to correct this.